# Using CloudKit, what does return fetchAllSubscriptionsWithCompletionHandler?

Tags: ios, cloudkit, cksubscription

I'm working alone on an app so, when using `fetchAllSubscriptionsWithCompletionHandler`on my CloudKit database, it returns only my subscriptions. Will it be the same when the app will have more users or does it return all the subscriptions on the database?

More broadly, is a subscription in CloudKit a link between a user and the database? Does it mean that if a user uses my app both on an iPad and an iPhone she can have only one subscription and it will be enough to notify both her devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are correct the documentation is a bit fuzzy on this but reading through it I see that subscriptions are per user and notifications for those subscriptions will be sent to ALL the users devices using that iCloud account.

The hint is in the fetchAllSubscriptionsOperation() Method